# Why does ''rm "$dir"/* !(.gitignore)'' delete the script itself?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have this shell script that I'm using to clean up some temp files.
The script is stored in: **/root/cronjobs**.
When I run the script from this location **./cleanUploader.sh**, it deletes all the files in the current folder along with itself.
Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# cleanUploader.sh
# Batch file to remove various temp directories and files left over from the Uploader

clear
echo 

INHOUSEFILES=/var/www/html/inhouseweb/officedb/uploader/files

shopt -s extglob
if [ -d $INHOUSEFILES ]; then
    echo "Removing directory $INHOUSEFILES"
    rm -rf $INHOUSEFILES/* !(".gitignore")
else
    echo "directory $INHOUSEFILES not found"
fi
echo

shopt -u extglob

echo
echo "Done"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that you should really be quoting `[ -d "$INHOUSEFILES" ]`. (And ideally, not giving it an all-caps name; those are used by the shell and POSIX-defined tools for environment and built-in variables that change their operation, whereas names with at least one lowercase character are guaranteed not to modify POSIX-defined tools' behavior when used by applications -- see the relevant standard at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rm -rf $INHOUSEFILES/* !(".gitignore")
```

This deletes all files in `$INHOUSEFILES/*`, and then it *also* deletes everything in the *current* directory except `.gitignore`. That's what `!(".gitignore")` does when it's a separate argument.

If your intention is to delete everything in `$INHOUSEFILES/` except `.gitignore` then combine the two arguments:

```
rm -rf $INHOUSEFILES/!(".gitignore")
```

It's also a good idea to quote variable expansions. (And conversely you don't need them around a literal string like `.gitignore`.)

```
rm -rf "$INHOUSEFILES"/!(.gitignore)
```

Comment: Wouldn't without `dotglob` the `.gitinore` file not be deleted anyway?

Comment: Right, `*` doesn't match hidden files by default. Perhaps the OP wants to delete hidden files except for `.gitignore`? I dunno, up to them.